# how to identify all libc calls at compile time?

Tags: linux, libc

I'd like to do some analysis of C code on Linux/BSD to see the frequency of library functions being used. So basically I'd like to compile the code and after the compilation step somehow print out all the functions this code uses. For example: "chown, mmap, etc, etc". I want to run this over a few thousand open source applications so looking for automation.

Is there a way to do this?

Note. dynamic instrumentation like strace or ptrace wouldn't work for me as I cannot run all the applications and even if i did i may not go through every single code path so might miss some calls that are possible (ie. calls that only happen in error conditions)

Comment: I would start from looking into `strace`.

Comment: You can probably get this information during the linking process. Check `ld` options?

Comment: thanks. i added a note why strace wouldn't work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `objdump -T | grep GLIBC` on the compiled binary.

For example:

```
$ objdump -T /bin/lessecho|grep GLIBC
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 putchar
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 puts
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.4   __stack_chk_fail
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 strchr
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 __libc_start_main
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 strcmp
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.3.4 __printf_chk
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 exit
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 fwrite
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.3.4 __fprintf_chk
0000000000000000  w   DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 __cxa_finalize
0000000000202040 g    DO .bss   0000000000000008  GLIBC_2.2.5 stderr
```

Also `nm -D` will show similar data.

Comment: objdump didn't work for me on my platform, but nm -D seems to give some info. Thanks for the hint!